# 2023 Edition: Why does my iPhone turn on when I plug it in to charge? And, how can I stop it from doing so?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, charging

As of 2023 is there a way, anyway at all (short of bricking it), to prevent my iPhone 13 from starting up automatically when I plug it in to charge when it is already turned off, or if it is fully discharged?

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: You can always shut it down _after_ you plug it in. I've been doing that for so many years now it has become automatic for all my iDevices. Adopt, adapt and improve, I always say.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way at all to prevent your iPhone 13 from starting up automatically when you plug it in to charge.